# Write file if PHPUnit assert failed

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit to test generated images using Imagick.

Currently I write every generated image to a file, so I can see it when an assert fails. After the asserts the file is deleted again.

This works, but all the file access is slowing down the test run. Is it possible to instead only write a file to disk if an assert failed?

Comment: Can't you just have the data of proper images in data fixtures and assert if the generated image data equals what you expect? I'd also consider if the tests are testing something that belongs to the project or Imagick, usually you'd want your dependencies/libs to have their own test suites so you don't have to test them in your application.

Comment: @JimL that is what I'm doing now, compare images known to be correct to images generated. But if this comparison fails, I need to be able to look at the generated image to see what it is different. Also, I'm not testing Imagick, I'm testing my own code that uses Imagick. It's simply the same as any other unit testing, except my output is not text but images.

Comment: could you please show your assertion statement(s)?

Comment: Ok :) Then I'd probably create a custom "image equal" assertion. [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html), [example](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/02/phpunit-writing-a-custom-assertion/) where you'd be able to conditionally do things (like creating images) on assertion fails

Comment: Consider implementing a test listener https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Jakub Zalas`suggestion to look at creating a Listener, I found out about the`onNotSuccessfulTest`, which allows you to add things to your test to do when a test fails.

```
class MyPHPUnit_Framework_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $failureFiles = [];

    protected function writeFileOnFailure($filename, $content)
    {
        @unlink($filename);
        $this->failureFiles[$filename] = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @before
     */
    public function forgetFailureFiles()
    {
        $this->failureFiles = [];
    }

    public function onNotSuccessfulTest(\Exception $e)
    {
        foreach ($this->failureFiles as $filename => $content) {
            file_put_contents($filename, $content);
        }
        $this->failureFiles = [];

        parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
    }

}
```

Just inherit this and call `$this->writeFileOnFailure($path, $content)` before the assert statement. The rest is handled automatically. You could call `$this->forgetFailureFiles()` if you have more asserts in your test method, but no longer care about the files, but otherwise it'll be called before every new test method automatically.

There are probably better ways to handle this (like using a Listener or Decorator), but this is pretty simple to implement and change for specific needs.